# iPhone 5s Phantom Photos Will Not Delete

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, disk-space

I  have about 14GB of space taken-up by photos that aren't there.  I've seen the date reset to delete recently deleted photos, however that does not work for me.  I do not want to reset my iPhone to fix this problem if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  iOS devices have a delayed delete function.  To solve the "phantom photo/video" issue, do the following:

1. Delete what you want deleted
2. Open Photos app on iOS device.
3. Open 'Recently Deleted' folder.
4. Delete items from phone permanently.
5. (Re)plug phone into laptop and Sync.

The photos/videos size drop to appropriately after I did this.

Cheers.